# How do I prevent a Nikon D3100 from resetting the file image numbering each time?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3100, file-management

I have a Nikon D3100. When I unload the pictures from the camera to the computer, the numbering of the file names goes back to zero.

Sometimes, when they are still about the same event, I would prefer if it kept going where it left off. Is there a way to tweak those settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the Setup Menu (The one with the wrench icon) and set File Number Sequence to ON.

Comment: thanks for tip. i was actually looking the reverse way. wanted images to start at 0001 with enery shoot, and rename later. turned number sequence off.