# How to add the date/time on the file name of Nikon D3200

Tags: nikon, filenames

Right now, every picture I take are named like this DSC_0237.JPG
As a result, When I try to put the pictures in the same folders as other Nikon pictures, the filenames overlap. 
How to add the date and time in this naming format automatically?
Something like: DSC_0237_20180302_131525

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent a Nikon D3100 from resetting the file image numbering each time?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/how-do-i-prevent-a-nikon-d3100-from-resetting-the-file-image-numbering-each-time) which will stop the counter resetting. You then only have to change DSC to DSD, DSE etc every 10, 000 shots. I know of no way to make it add a date.

Comment: No, I know of this feature but I want to put the date/time or even a short random string. The goal is to differentiate the file to other Nikon filename

Comment: That method will differentiate your first ten thousand images. Further differentiation is done by changing the prefix to something other than DSC - https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/using-the-file-naming-feature-in-a-nikon-dslr-camera.html

Comment: If you want the naming to be done in camera, you can't.

Comment: You'll have to use a helper app/tool to rename the files. I'd recommend exiftool.

Answer (score 4):

There is no option to change the file name in camera. Users can only change the file number sequence method, as @Tetsujin noted. For the record:

In *Setup Menu*, change *File Number Sequence* to *On*. The camera will continuously number images and give them all a unique filename. After 999 images, use the *Reset* option in *File Number Sequence* to go back to 001. See the [D3100](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/sDcfr00jEJ5F01Yssec54ma3bq70/D3100RM_EU(En)04.pdf) manual for more details.

Changing the name for each shoot has to be done outside of the camera. The import tool in your digital asset management program will have an option for that. Alternately, use a free-standing app for bulk file renaming.